# c# datatable.select() order by null last

Tags: c#, datatable

The below code i tried for selecting Datarow[] from datatable by filtering and sorting.

```
Datarow[] dr=dtable.select("filter","name ASC").
```

the above sorting returns null first.

how to order by nulls last

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like,

```
DataRow[] dr = dtable.Select("filter", "name ASC")
                     .OrderByDescending(x => x["name"] != DBNull.Value)
                     .ToArray();
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: `OrderByDescending` just resorts your datarow array in the descending order based on the boolean value that it gets by checking the `name` column value.

Comment: so after filteration onl orderbydescending will work. Am i right?

Comment: Yes, after `filter` and `name ASC` sort, new descending operation is applied based on the nullability of the column, that is 1 or 0. So that your existing sort will persist and only the `null` values will be moved back.

Comment: I want to apply filter and order by together.

Comment: You mean this nullability descending order operation in the `Select` method itself!! Why, whats wrong with this operation? Now, the `Select` method returns you a bunch of `DataRow` records with sorted `name` column. After getting it, we are just resorting to put the null records back, thats it!!

Comment: I have a scenario like this. 1) Class: a , Name : null  2) Class : a, Name: abc 3) Class : a, Name : cdef.   I need class wise names with nulls last